# Will Moshiach actually be anointed?

Tags: messiah, oil

Seeking sources which discuss if Moshiach will in fact be anointed with oil and if so, which oil (newly processed, or the original anointing oil made by Moshe) how that process would take place (Sanhedrin, Kohen Gadol, Eliyahu?) and at what point it will happen.

Comment: See Minchas Chinuch Mitzvah 107:8

Comment: @שלום I believe he leaves off with tzarich iyun

Comment: Horayot 11b seems to say the original one from moshe was used for everything and will be used in the future ואותו שמן קיים לעתיד לבוא שנאמר שמן משחת קדש יהיה זה לי לדורותיכם

Comment: Related answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/59869/7303