# If Jews conquer a random new land does it become holy like Eretz Yisrael? How might this relate to kibbush yachid? And does kibbush yachid even count?

Tags: history, eretz-yisrael, malchut-royalty, contemporary-halacha

If Jews conquered New York City let's say does New York City become holy just like Eretz Yisrael?
What if a "Jewish king" declared it as a Jewish state? I'm very curious..

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya! You might want to split this question into multiple questions, so that each one can garner attention and answers separately. It's also probable that "Can we have a Jewish king nowadays anyway" has already been asked.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45589/can-the-jewish-people-have-a-king-while-in-exile this should answer your last question